# Angular use functions 2 ways within Libs

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, circular-dependency

I have a question I have generated 2 Libs in Angular.
Lib 1 wants to use an exported function of Lib 2. But lib 2 also wants to use an exported
function of lib 1. When i try to do this angular gets stuck because of circular dependency is there a way to fix this?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 Services:

```
export class Service1 {
    constructor(private readonly m_service2: Service2){}
    doSomething(){ this.m_service2.doSomething(); }
}

export class Service2 {
    constructor(private readonly m_service1: Service1){}
    doSomething(){ this.m_service1.doSomething(); }
}
```

This is a typical circular dependency conflict.

To solve it, you can create another service `Service3`, which holds the function `doSomething` and is injected into the other services.

```
export class Service1 {
    constructor(private readonly m_service3: Service3){}
    doSomething(){ this.m_service3.doSomething(); }
}

export class Service2 {
    constructor(private readonly m_service3: Service3){}
    doSomething(){ this.m_service3.doSomething(); }
}

export class Service3 {
    doSomething(){ /* do something */ }
}
```

Comment: I am using directly exported functions. the thing is that if a use a function of lib1 in lib 2 i cant use a function of lib2 in lib1 dont see how exactly this is going to fix it

Comment: @Hans You could create a "lib 3" that holds the shared functions, which both your other libs can access. It's the same approach as the one I shared in my answer.

Comment: so basically there is no other way then splitting it up?

Comment: @Hans You could also duplicate the functions you need from lib 2 in lib 1 and vice versa, but I wouldn't exactly say that this is the best thing to do.